# In windows azure biztalk services (WABS) how to geneate all unmapped nodes in the output xml?

Tags: biztalk

How to generate unmapped tags in the transformation output?

I am using windows azure biztalk srvices, in my mapper's RHS, few elements are unmapped and those are not getting generated in the output xml. A a result, it doesn't pass the schema validation. How to solve this without adding empty string concatenation functiod?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a BizTalk Services Mapping before me. So I don't know if you have the option also for the BizTalk Services Mapping.

On the output schema you select the node you need in the Output.
Search for the value property. On premise you have a dropdown with "< empty >". So it will create an empty node...